# Dynamic template in listview (WinJS) in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have a windows 8 application with a simple listview in a list layout. I have fetched my blog items (syndication), now what I want to achieve is add a dynamic item that will function as a "load more" button. To do this, I want to specify a different template just for this item. The sample I have found uses a function template, which really isn't very versatile since I have to load all template elements using JavaScript. Is there a way to dynamically specify a WinJS.Binding.Template based on an item property?

Comment: Let me clarify this a bit more: I do not want to use a javascript function in order to render the two templates by code, because each template is fairly complex. I want to define two WinJS.Binding.Template divs, and dynamically select which one to use for each item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excellent article on the subject

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2012/05/23/metro-dynamically-switching-templates-with-a-winjs-listview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I actually had the same problem before. The way I handle this problem is as following:

```
function listItemTemplateRenderer(item) {

    //Get data from item.
    var data = item._value.data;

    // if it is a special item renderer, apply special template
    if (data.isSpecialItem) {
        return specialItemRenderer(data);
    }

    var itemElement = document.createElement('div');
    itemElement.className = "listItemTemplate";

    var placeHolder = document.createElement('div');
    placeHolder.className = "itemTemplateClass";
    placeHolder.id = data.id;

    var itemDetail = document.createElement('div');
    itemDetail.className = "itemDetailStyle";

    ... //whatever you wanna add to your template

    //Append child elements
    placeHolder.appendChild(itemDetail);
    itemElement.appendChild(placeHolder);

    return {
        element: itemElement
    };
}

// Template for the special item
function messageItemRenderer(item) {

    var itemElement = document.createElement('div');
    itemElement.className = "listItemTemplat";

    var placeHolder = document.createElement('div');
    placeHolder.className = "specialItemTemplate";
    placeHolder.id = item.id;

    var dataText = document.createElement('div');
    dataText.className = "dataText";
    dataText.innerText = item.text;
    placeHolder.appendChild(dataText);

    itemElement.appendChild(placeHolder);

    itemElement.onclick = item.clickHandler;

    return {
        element: itemElement
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the last part of this tutorial "**[Using a function to display items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700705.aspx)**" can help you. Within the function you can determine which item there is in your list and render a different template. It also would be possible to load the different templates from your HTML file.

Another option that you might have is to use the [pagesToLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211839.aspx) property in combination with the [automaticallyLoadPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700671.aspx) property. This will automatically start loading new items when the user scrolls to the end of the listbox.